# How to use iconv or similar to convert a UTF-16BE string to human readable characters

Tags: bash, encoding, rhel, utf-16, iconv

I have the following data in `UTF-16BE`:

```
00 33 00 33 00 30 00 33 00 20 00 43 00 39 00 32 00 00
```

I am trying to convert this to human readable format for further use in a bash script.

The above should resolve to "`3303 C92`"

Currently I've made it this far but im obviously getting something wrong.

```
iconv -f UTF-16BE -t ASCII /home/code.txt #string above is only thing in this file.
```

command error: `iconv: illegal input sequence at position 0`

I am using RHEL 7

Comment: Can you describe what you're trying to do more clearly? If the UTF-16BE string isn't in a variable or a file, where is it? And where are you trying to store the converted version? Does the `iconv` command you have work when the UTF-16BE string is in a file?

Comment: my mistake, Ideally I would be using the string as a variable, pass it through conversion and ouput to another variable. The UTF string presents the following error: illegal input sequence at position 0       if I force it to go forward with iconv -f UTF-16BE -t ASCII//TRANSLIT   the returned string is gibberish

Comment: `the following data in UTF-16BE` This is a hexdump of the content of the file? Or you have the actual literal digits characters and spaces characters stored in the file? `echo '00 33 00 33 00 30 00 33 00 20 00 43 00 39 00 32 00 00 ' | xxd -r -p | iconv -f UTF-16BE -t ASCII` Works fine for me.

Comment: From the error, it sounds like you don't have raw UTF-16BE, you have a *hexadecimal representation of* UTF-16BE (i.e. your input actually starts with the characters "0", "0", and a space, rather than a null byte). Is that correct?

Comment: Correct no null byte, the characters in the string should be in groups of 4 if im not mistaken.... This data was curled from an xml file and trimmed.... the manufacturer of the device that generated the file stated the encoding was in UTF-16BE with no further elaboration.

Answer (score 0):

The last byte (00) is extra.

```bash
> base64 -d <<<"ADMAMwAwADMAIABDADkAMgA=" | iconv -f utf-16be -t ascii
3303 C92iconv: incomplete character or shift sequence at end of buffer
```

After removing last byte:

```bash
> base64 -d <<<"ADMAMwAwADMAIABDADkAMg==" | iconv -f utf-16be -t ascii
3303 C92
```